# Facebook SDK Login dialog appears twice

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

In my project is the next code which sends some message to user feed:

```
[facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];
[facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

But when I call function with this code, login dialog appears twice. How can I solve this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 9):

*Login dialog is not appearing twice. Two Login dialogs are appearing at the same time*. Both the above lines will open a dialog. So if you call those lines together, two dialogs will be opened together. If you are not already logged in to `Facebook`, obviously both the dialogs will open the Login page.

First, call

```
[facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];
```

Once you logged in and the authorization is over, call

```
[facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

Answer (score 1):

Hii Paul :

You are calling FB Dialog two times - the First part this is login part when you have no fb session

```
[facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];
```

When u invoke the first one, then you need to call this method to publish dialog in

```
- (void) fbDidLogin {
    [facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
}
```

if u already have your FB Sesssion then you can directly call the second part :

```
[facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```