# IOS Facebook sdk login Dialog shows up twice (2 login dialogs)

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, sdk

my question is very similar to this: 
[Facebook SDK Login dialog appears twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235879/facebook-sdk-login-dialog-appears-twice)

" login dialog appears twice. How can I solve this problem?"

Except, I am using this singleton for communicating with the Facebook sdk: 
http://matt-swain.com/post/21160566904/facebook-ios-sdk-singleton (thats the code I'm using)
http://barrycenter.com/BAM!coding/2011/07/simplifying-facebook-ios-sdk/ (old version including explanations)

The only difference between my code and the original singleton one is that I have a method:

```
-(void) postToWallWithDialog:(int)count2 {

    NSMutableDictionary* params = [self buildPostParams:count2];
    [self dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self]; //post 

} //buildPostParams just makes a dictionary, nothing else.
```

I do not want to call my method from within fbDidLogin, because it needs to be called from the view controller.

how do i eliminate the second login dialog?

thanks!

Comment: my code works if I call to post from fbDidlogin ... but i want to call it from the view controller. Any way to do this using NSUserNotifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using FBNotifications to check if user in fact flogged in and whether or not there was a valid session. Knowing that, I posted to the wall and it eliminated the second dialog.