# Why Facebook SDK ask authorization for twice?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am implementing my project with the aid of Facebook SDK (iOS).
And I encountered a strange phenomenon...

I first put the initialization codes for the Facebook object:

```
self.facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:appID andDelegate:self];
```

And then I will check if the token is available and if not, go to my login view...

Then I added a button which will trigger the login to Facebook method in my app delegate and in which I only called the authorize method

```
- (void)LoginToFacebook
{
    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"email",nil];
    [self.facebook authorize:permissions];
}
```

and handle the transitions with this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
 sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
     annotation:(id)annotation
{
    // attempt to extract a token from the url
    return [self.facebook handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

The problem I encounter is, when I reset my simulator and run the project, at first everything is alright, that my login page is shown. When I pressed the login button,
it first asked me to login (NORMAL), and then authorize the app. However, when I pressed the Okay button (assume I've already authorized the app before), in the program fbDidLogin is called, yet another safari window is popped-up and is asking for authorization again ...

I've been searching for solutions and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235879/facebook-sdk-login-dialog-appears-twice?lq=1) which said one doesn't want to put the authorize method and feed dialog at the same place. Yet, in my code I didn't do such things (I did have app request dialog code but I'm quite sure they are not put at the same place).

Moreover, after I pressed the Okay button twice, it goes to the logged in page with error code 400.... and when I clicked another button for getting user's friends, it succeed.

The strange phenomenon is that, if I did get the user's friends and the logout and login again, the same code only pop up ONE safari window for authorization.....

So I have been quite confused, so anyone can help me?

## EDIT

I just found out that, if I don't include permissions, the app runs fine, but if I include it, the problem is still there that Safari pops up for two times at the first time of logging in...